# Store bpy.context.selected_objects for later

Tags: python, add-on

Hello I'm looking for an optimised way to store a list in the Blend File. I'm guessing I need to use Property Groups

Basically what i Need is a way to store:

```
bpy.context.selected_objects
```

In a list

This list should be able to be accessed at anywhere and only be cleared when a method specifically clears it. e.g not disappear when Blend-file is saved and closed and then reopened.

Reading, storing, and clearing list needs to not take too much time since this list might change within 1 second when a slider is changing.

Comment: `lis = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]`

Comment: No this is not a solution. it's not saved when leaving the function or closing the blend-file

Comment: How about save the data in blend file?

Comment: I think you want to look into using a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Save some data in blend file

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj["my_attr"] = True

# not work for unsaved file
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

#### The next time the file is opened

```
import bpy

lis = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if "my_attr" in obj]
```

Comment: cool that's pretty useful